# PDF created with FPDF and how to save and retrieve the pdf

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

How do I store a PDF created by FPDF in a MySQL database?

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions here. [faq] [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Your Database:**

- Set cloumn type to BLOB

**Save:**

```
//make a pdf
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

//set pdf to savable type
$pdfcontent = $pdf->Output("", "S");

//save pdf to database
$mysqli=new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pdfs (pdf) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pdfcontent);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Retrieve:**

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT pdf FROM pdfs WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($pdfcontent);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($pdfcontent) );
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="WarriorDeals_Voucher_'.$number.'-'.$numIndex.'.pdf"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
    echo $pdfcontent;
}
```

Comment: hai Dan Kanze i am not clear this line values---->>  
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pdfs (pdf) VALUES (?)");

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you truly need to save the resultant PDF to the database?  Perhaps you could persist the PDF to the file system, and save the path to the file in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but in case it's what I think you're asking...
You will need the root path as well as the file name you use to store the file to create a proper database entry. You have to use a mysql databse and and an insert query to input it as long as a select query to retrieve its location and use it in your website. 
Read the basics of PHP/mySQL at w3schools and also considering FPDF, read the uploaded FAQ [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php).