# created Pdf using Html2pdf i don't know how to save and retrieve pdf

Tags: php, mysql, html2pdf

i am created Pdf using Html2pdf ,i don't know how to save and retrieve pdf, i am new in php   please help me 
thanks in advance

Comment: their documentation explains a lot. What do you really want. Are you stuck somewhere? if yes, plz show your code

Comment: Duplicate of [PDF created with FPDF and how to save and retrieve the pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9437761) please do not repost questions; read the advice on the original question instead, where you already got answers.

Comment: sorry now i change pdf creation  fpdf to html2pdf , because it was simple to make a pdf .That is  the reason for i am asking second time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as you can see in example in [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/it/example)

```
<?php
    $content = "
<page>
    <h1>Exemple d'utilisation</h1>
    <br>
    Ceci est un <b>exemple d'utilisation</b>
    de <a href='http://html2pdf.fr/'>HTML2PDF</a>.<br>
</page>";

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content); // in $content you put your content to have in pdf
    $html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
?>
```

EDIT:
with this you save on server.

```
  $html2pdf->Output('directory/filename_xxxx.pdf', 'F');
  Add the name to mysqldb.
```

When you want pdf content,you will get name from db and make what you need :)

Comment: i completed this one i want to save & retrieve in to mysql database