# Setting up production on a virtual web server for Mac, Apache, PHP and MySql

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I'm building a web app on my Mac and have so far been testing with XAMPP. I'm looking at finding a virtual server vendor to host my application but have found almost none that is compatible with Mac, Apache, PHP and MySql. I don't want to go the Mac Mini route for now.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this or what vendor to use?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a PHP/mySQL app, chances are it's not very dependent on the OS it's running on. Unless you have something totally Mac specific running in your app, getting a normal Linux VPS may be  the way to go.

Comment: Where is your *programming* problem?

Comment: @Matthias there are grey areas. See e.g. the wildly popular [Pre-installed Linux for Web Developers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2154457)

Comment: Well, then rather little. :-(

Comment: @Matthias true, but is it a big deal? Stack Overflow has a lot more serious problems than the occasional slightly off-topic question. IMHO. Random examples from this month: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437761) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443043/created-pdf-using-html2pdf-i-dont-know-how-to-save-and-retrieve-pdf) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343583) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093567)

Comment: @Matthias. This is my first post to SOF and I'm new to the community. Here's to hoping that community users are not as negative or this may end up being a very sort lived signup.